# Prompt browser to download a file throgh Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets, download

When I click on a link , I want to call my API in my "JobDownload" servlet and download the response as a file in browser. The API returns a multipart response which I convert to Input Stream. I am able to show contents returned after calling servlet in console.log() below, but unable to open browser download box.

I call like this :

```
$("#filename").click(function(){
    alert("Download initiated");
    $.get('jobDownload', {'key': jobDownId,'name':jobFileName}, 
        function (data) {
           console.log("Data Downloaded"+data);                                
         });
});
```

My servlet looks like this :

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String jobId = request.getParameter("key");
        String fileName = request.getParameter("name");

        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        System.out.println("\n\nJob ID is :"+jobId+"\nFilename is :"+fileName);

        // Calling my API which will return an InputStream
        InputStream jobResult = getJobResultById(jobId);

        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("\n\nInputStream of job is here");

        // Stream the inputStream to outputStream
        streamOutput(jobResult, os);
        System.out.println("\n\nOutStream of job is here");
    }
```

And my streamOutput method is like this :

```
public void streamOutput(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        BufferedInputStream dis = null;
        try {
            dis = new BufferedInputStream(new DataInputStream(is));
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int nread = dis.read(buf);
            while (nread != -1) {
                os.write(buf, 0, nread);
                nread = dis.read(buf);
            }
            // flush the output as soon as possible to prevent client timeouts
            // we can delay cleaning up the inputstream 
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        dis = null;
    }
```

I am not getting that browser download dialog box which user should click to download this result. Do I need to add anything in my Jquery method or add something in my java code